# How to plot a frequency plot use python

Tags: python

Ive a question about python plotting. How to make a frequency plot for example how to see some behaviours’ frequency ( coded as True or False) based on time of the dat (coded as AM or PM)

My ideal plot will be like this but indicates frequency of some behaviour that varies by time of the dat

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4]})
df['numbers'].value_counts().plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', xlabel='numbers', ylabel='frequency')

plt.show()

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and thanks for answering! When adding code to a response/question, it's always best if you format it to make your post more readable. You can find an explanation [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).